# How to make condition in angularjs inside image src

Tags: angularjs

How to make the above codes work by using one `<img>`. I mean I want to use only one `<img>` but the conditions are the same. For now I'm using 2 img for condition and it's not good. How can I make it to use one img only. Any help?

```
   <img ng-if="!image[$index].dataUrl" ng-src="/upload/image/rotation_banner/{{row.Image}}"/>

   <img ng-show = "image[$index].dataUrl" ng-src="{{image[$index].dataUrl}}" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this out:

```
<img ng-src="{{image[$index].dataUrl ? image[$index].dataUrl : '/upload/image/rotation_banner/' + row.Image}}" />
```

Hope this helps.